# Intersection of finite collection of open sets is open

Tags: analysis

Can someone help me through this theorem in 'Baby Rudin.'

*For any collection $G_{1},...,G_{n}$ of open sets, $\bigcap\limits_{i = 1}^{n} G_{i}$ is open.*

**Pf**
Put $H = \bigcap\limits_{i=1}^{n} G_{i}$.  For any $x \in H$, there exist neighborhoods $N_{i}$ of $x$, with radii $r_{i}$, such that $N_{i} \subset G_{i}\ (i = 1,...,n)$.  Put $$r = min(r_{1},...,r_{n})$$ and let $N$ be the neighborhood of $x$ of radius $r$.  Then $N \subset G_{i}$ for $i = 1,...,n$, so that $N \subset H$, and $H$ is open.

$\Box$

So I am having difficulty in seeing why we are able to say the neighborhood $N_{r}(x)$ is a subset of $G_{i}$ for every $i$.  I am not following here.  Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: The "theorem" is actually trivial from the definition of a topology. I don't think you have learned that yet, though.

Comment: Also, I don't have time to write a proof, but think intuitionistically, maybe in $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Comment: Thanks for the comment.  That is where I am not following, geometrically.  $r$ can be large no?  I don't see what implies that $r$ is small enough.

Answer (score 1):

For each $i$, $r \leq r_i$. Thus $N_r(x) \subset N_i$ for each $i$. But $N_i \subset G_i$ for each $i$. Thus it immediately follows that $N_r(x) \subset G_i$ for each $i$.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  Though, I don't see how we can say that $r$ is small enough so that the neighborhood of $N_{r}(x)$ is contained  in the intersection.  If that makes sense... I don't see how saying since $N_{r_{i}}(x)$ is a neighborhood in the respective $G_{i}$, we have that it is a neighborhood in the intersection.  $r$ could be large, is what I am thinking...

Comment: @zzz2991 you have $N_r(x) \subset N_i \subset G_i$ for every $i$. Thus $N_r(x) \subset G_i$ for every $i$ thus $N_r(x)$ is in the intersection of the $G_i$.